# Get duration of using app for user from log table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table in which I'm recording logins/logouts. Schema and sample data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1b35/1

I need to create stored procedure which will print sum of (logout-login) times for an user and date (duration of using application for user on date). In column type I represents login and O logout.

Input parameters: @username, @date. Output: time.

Comment: Instead of using 'I' and 'O', use 1 for login, and -1 for logout.

Comment: njk, why not 0 for logout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to identify all groups of logins that are related to each other.  The way I would do this is by finding the logout associated with logins.  You are dealing with log data, so don't be surprised if there are multiple logins with no logout.

```
select l.*,
       (select min(l2.time) from logs l2 where l2.username = l.username and l2.type = 'O' and l2.time > l.time
       ) as logoutTime
from logs l
where l.type = 'I'
```

Now, you can use the username and LogoutTime as a pair for aggregation to get what you want:

```
select username, logoutTime, min(time) as StartTime, logouttime as EndTime,
       datediff(s, min(time), logoutTime) as TimeInSeconds
from (select l.*,
             (select min(l2.time) from logs l2 where l2.username = l.username and l2.type = 'O' and l2.time > l.time
             ) as logoutTime
      from logs l
      where l.type = 'I'
     ) l
group by username, logoutTime
```

Note that you specify SQL Server as a tag, but the SQL Fiddle is for MySQL; date functions tend to differ among databases.

And, if you are using SQL Server 2012, there is an easier way.  You should specify that if it is the case.

Comment: i'm using sql server 2008, forgot to change it in sqlfiddle. your query isn't working for me, endtime = starttime, timeinseconds is always 0. thx. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1b35/1

Comment: Oops, I fixed the problem.  (I forgot I had filtered out the "O" rows in the subquery, so `max(time)` did not include that data.  Of course, the max time is in logoutTime, so it is easily fixed.)

Comment: Gordon Linoff, why do you need the outer level of aggregation?  I'm getting the same results without it

Answer (score 0):

This is Gordon Linoff's solution, modified so it doesn't include the outermost level of aggregation, and uses clearer aliases, IMO

```
select username,time_in,time_out_min,
       datediff(s, time_in, time_out_min) as TimeInSeconds
from (
select i.username, i.time as time_in,
       (select min(o.time) as min_time_out
        from logs o 
        where o.username = i.username and 
        o.type = 'O' and 
        o.time > i.time
       ) as time_out_min
from logs i
where i.type = 'I'
  ) d;
```